# How can I add iCloud Documents capabilities to my application without using Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, marmalade, marmalade-edk

My app crashes with an "Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement" when either of the following two lines is executed:

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController* documentPicker =
  [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc]
    initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"]
                   inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];

UIDocumentMenuViewController *documentMenu =
  [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc]
    initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"]
                   inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

The [Document Picker Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) states that "Before your app can use the document picker, you must turn on the iCloud Documents capabilities in Xcode."

However, my app is not built with Xcode: it is built using third-party tools (the cross-platform toolkit, [Marmalade](http://madewithmarmalade.com)), so I cannot do this.

It should still be possible to turn on iCloud Documents capabilities for this app manually — the switch in iCloud simply automates the process — but my attempts to do so have not fixed the crash.

### What I've tried so far

Xcode displays the steps it carries out when switching on iCloud:

1. Add the "iCloud" entitlement to your App ID
2. Add the "iCloud containers" entitlement to your App ID
3. Add the "iCloud" entitlement to your entitlements file
4. Link CloudKit.framework

I also found Apple's [Entitlements Troubleshooting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2415/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016427-CH1-INTRODUCTION) TechNote, which describes steps that can be taken to check that the following steps have been carried out correctly.

I have enabled iCloud on my App ID:

[image: Screenshot of App ID showing iCloud is enabled]

I'm not certain whether this is necessary to use the document picker's simple import and export operations, but I also set up an iCloud container with the id `iCloud.com.[company].[app]`.

I have generated an updated provisioning profile that includes the iCloud entitlements:

[image: Screenshot of Provisioning Profile showing iCloud Service is enabled]

I inspected the downloaded provisioning profile using the command:

```
security cms -D -i /path/to/iOSTeamProfile.mobileprovision
```

It includes the following entries:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
<string>*</string>
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment</key>
<array>
  <string>Development</string>
  <string>Production</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
  <string>iCloud.com.[company].[app]</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-development-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
  <string>iCloud.com.[company].[app]</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
  <string>iCloud.com.[company].[app]</string>
</array>
```

Marmalade uses this provisioning profile to generate the entitlements file for the app.

I have inspected the generated entitlements using the following command:

```
codesign -d --ent :- [App.app]
```

Which gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>application-identifier</key>
  <string>[team-id].com.[company].[app]</string>
  <key>aps-environment</key>
  <string>development</string>
  <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-development-container-identifiers</key>
  <array>
    <string>iCloud.com.[company].[app]</string>
  </array>
  <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment</key>
  <array>
    <string>Development</string>
    <string>Production</string>
  </array>
  <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
  <array>
    <string>iCloud.com.[company].[app]</string>
  </array>
  <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
  <string>*</string>
  <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
  <string>[team-id]</string>
  <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
  <array>
    <string>iCloud.com.[company].[app]</string>
  </array>
  <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
  <string>[team-id].*</string>
  <key>get-task-allow</key>
  <true/>
  <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
  <array>
    <string>[team-id].com.[company].[app]</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, the app still crashes whenever the functions are called.

I also found [this old guide to setting up iCloud in Marmalade apps](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/macieks/s3eIOSiCloud/master/SETUP.txt). Most of the steps seem no longer to be necessary/possible, but I followed the suggestion to add the `application-identifier` key to my Info.plist.

What else do I need to do to add iCloud Documents capabilities to my app?

Comment: have you added the privacy message, since iOS10 you have to ask user for permission, so in native apps you add privacy statements in the .plist which is the message telling the user why you need access

Comment: @SeanLintern88 I haven't, but I'm currently testing on a device with iOS 8. So I don't think that can be the issue? Also, I can't find a privacy purpose string for either invoking Document Pickers or using iCloud in [this list](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html). To which plist key do you refer?

Comment: @Rich, same problem. Did you solve?

Comment: @Giorgio No luck so far. Please do post an answer if you fix it!

Comment: @Rich, Have you tried to set 
CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = <your_entitlements_file_name> in Build Settings?

Comment: @Giorgio No, I edited Marmalade's `sign_app.py` script to use a known-correct entitlements file instead of auto-generating a file. (Crash still occurs.)

Comment: @Giorgio See my answer below for how we eventually fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marmalade generates the `.xcent` entitlements file used when signing the app by copying over the "Entitlements" `dict` from the provisioning profile.

The problem was caused by the value associated with the [undocumented](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH2-SW2) key:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
<string>*</string>
```

This appears to be *valid* in the provisioning profile, but *invalid* when signed into the app. Replacing those elements in the generated `.xcent file` with the following and then re-signing the app fixed the issue:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
<array>
  <string>CloudDocuments</string>
</array>
```

*(N.B. If you also use CloudKit, you will also need to add a `CloudKit` `string` to the `array`.)*

In practice, we fixed this by editing Marmalade's `sign_app.py` script to use a pre-prepared `.xcent` file (copied over from the `DerivedData` directory of the functioning app we built with Xcode) when signing the app:

In file `/Applications/Marmalade.app/Contents/s3e/deploy/plugins/iphone` edit line 557:

```
cmd += ['--entitlements', xcentfile.name]
```

...replacing `xcentfile.name` with the path to the pre-prepared `.xcent` file.